# How to read/modify form data that goes through Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to validate and log form data that goes through Spring Cloud Gateway. I have tried a few methods and encounter a few problems and I could not read it properly. I have tried:

```
@Component
public class GatewayRequestFilter {


    @Bean
    public GlobalFilter apply() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            MediaType contentType = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType();
            ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config modifyRequestConfig = new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config();


            /// Method 1
            if (contentType.includes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)) {
                modifyRequestConfig.setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, (exchange1, originalRequestBody) -> {
                    validateAndAuditLog(exchange1, originalRequestBody);
                    return Mono.just(originalRequestBody);
                });
            }


            /// Method 2    
            if (contentType.includes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)) {
                return exchange.getMultipartData().flatMap(originalRequestBody -> {
                    validateAndAuditLog(exchange1, originalRequestBody);
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                });
            }


            /// Method 3:
            /// https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1307#issuecomment-553910834


            return new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory().apply(modifyRequestConfig).filter(exchange, chain);
        };
    }
}
```

For the 1st and 3rd method, if I set inClass as String.class then I can see data in some kind of http format. The problem is that I don't know how to parse it into hashMap or LinkedMultiValueMap to access each of value using key. Here is the output I get:

```
----------------------------162653831591335516327921
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="simple-text"

text
----------------------------162653831591335516327921
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="simple-file"; filename="simple-file"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Simple file 

----------------------------162653831591335516327921--
```

If I change inClass as Object.class then there is another error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-03T02:37:57.096+0000",
    "path": "/tc/test/test",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------537619313111072161580699' not supported for bodyType=java.lang.Object",
    "requestId": "0592497a-1"
}
```

For the 2nd method I can get data in LinkedMultiValueMap which is good because I can read each data using key value and I can also get uploaded files name, but the problem is that, it hang for 10s before pass the request to down stream.

Anyone has any idea what should I do to read or modify form data that goes through Spring Cloud Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the answer with example.

Basic approach is defined here, though it needs lot of refinement to work for multi-part.
https://developpaper.com/question/how-to-modify-the-request-parameters-of-multipart-form-data-format-in-spring-cloud-gateway/

For any approach to work once you read the data, you need to set a modified request object to exchange downstream to be processed again. Setting the new multi-part object downstream is bit tricky because there is not a straightforward way to convert string->multi-part->string.

Here is a sample code based on the approach. Note that this for now works only if multi-part contains form fields and not file type fields, because in later case we are dealing with a stream, which can be embedded anywhere within the entire multi-part request, and it is not possible to modify such request without blocking calls, which the netty does not allow.

```
private final List<HttpMessageReader<?>> messageReaders = HandlerStrategies.withDefaults().messageReaders();

public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerRequest serverRequest = ServerRequest.create(exchange, messageReaders);
            
            // get modified body from original body o
            Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>> modifiedBody = serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(o -> {
                // create mock request to read body
                SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader synchronossReader = new SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader();
                MultipartHttpMessageReader reader = new MultipartHttpMessageReader(synchronossReader);
                MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.post("").contentType(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType()).body(o);
                Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> monoRequestParts = reader.readMono(MULTIPART_DATA_TYPE, request, Collections.emptyMap());
                // modify parts
                return monoRequestParts.flatMap(requestParts -> {
                    Map<String, List<String>> modifedBodyArray = requestParts.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        LOGGER.info(key);
                        List<String> entries = entry.getValue().stream().map(part -> {
                            LOGGER.info("{}", part);
                            // read the input part
                            String input = ((FormFieldPart) part).value();
                            // return the modified input part
                            return new String(modifyRequest(config, exchange, key, input));
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new Map.Entry<String, List<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public String getKey() {
                                return key;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public List<String> getValue() {
                                return entries;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public List<String> setValue(List<String> param1) {
                                return param1;
                            }
                        };
                    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getKey(), k -> k.getValue()));
                    return Mono.just(new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(modifedBodyArray));
                });
            });
            
            // insert the new modified body
            BodyInserter bodyInserter = BodyInserters.fromPublisher(modifiedBody, new ParameterizedTypeReference<MultiValueMap<String, String>>() {});
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.putAll(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders());

            // the new content type will be computed by bodyInserter
            // and then set in the request decorator
            headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
            
            CachedBodyOutputMessage outputMessage = new CachedBodyOutputMessage(exchange, headers);
            return bodyInserter.insert(outputMessage, new BodyInserterContext())
                    .then(Mono.defer(() -> {
                        ServerHttpRequest decorator = decorate(exchange, headers, outputMessage);
                        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build());
                    }));

        }, RouteToRequestUrlFilter.ROUTE_TO_URL_FILTER_ORDER + 1);
    }

// some of the helper methods
    private String modifyRequest(Config config, ServerWebExchange exchange, String key, String input) {
        // do your thing in here !!!

        return input;
    }
    
    private ServerHttpRequestDecorator decorate(ServerWebExchange exchange, HttpHeaders headers, CachedBodyOutputMessage outputMessage) {
        return new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
            @Override
            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                long contentLength = headers.getContentLength();
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                httpHeaders.putAll(headers);
                if (contentLength > 0) {
                    httpHeaders.setContentLength(contentLength);
                } else {
                    // TODO: this causes a 'HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required' // on httpbin.org
                    httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked");
                }
                return httpHeaders;
            }

            @Override
            public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                return outputMessage.getBody();
            }
        };
    }
```